# SQL Query to update barcode table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I can do it with by code but just curious to know how we can do it with Update SQL command this sql query.
I have got a StockBarcode table where all barcodes are empty. My customer gave me a list of barcodes in Excel document and i copied all of them to BarcodeExcel table. (Copy and Paste)

Now i need to update Barcodes number from BarcodeExcel table to StockBarcode table.
[image]

I tried this but it creates a new table it is not UPDATE.

```
SELECT * INTO BarcodeNew2
FROM (SELECT SB.StockCode
  ,SB.SizeNo
  ,SB.Size
  ,BE.Barcode
 FROM StockBarcode SB
 LEFT JOIN BarcodeExcel BE ON SB.StockCode = BE.StockCode and SB.Size = BE.Size) x
```

I tried this with UPDATE but it is doesn't execute it. Syntax is wrong

```
UPDATE StockBarcode SC
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Helper]
          ,[StockCode]
          ,[Size]
          ,[Barcode]
      FROM [PEIStock].[dbo].[BarcodeExcel]
)BE ON SC.StockCode = BE.StockCode and SC.Size = BE.Size
SET  SC.Barcode = BE.Barcode
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join syntax for updating for the query is as follows:

```
UPDATE SC set barcode = BE.barcode from StockBarcode SC 
          inner join BarcodeExcel BE ON SC.StockCode = BE.StockCode and SC.Size = BE.Size
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the good istinct on the UPDATE. But the syntax is wrong.
A proper syntax : http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/

I do not have a SQL server running for now so I will give it a blunt try :

```
UPDATE StockBarcode 
SET t1.Barcode = t2.Barcode   
FROM
    StockBarcode t1
    INNER JOIN BarcodeExcel t2 
      ON  t1.StockCode = t2.StockCode 
      AND t1.Size = t2.Size;
```

Comment: Thank you Jaisus, It is almost working. because at the moment it says "The multi-part identifier "SC.Barcode" could not be bound." But if I remove t1 and use it like a SET Barcode = t2.Barcode  . It is working.